# How can I run a VS2015 application from the command line?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a VS2015 Cloud application developed using VS2015. When I am debugging I run this locally by clicking on Run in the VS2015.

I would like to reduce my memory requirements. Is there a way I can run this from a file in the bin directory or some other way?  Note the application does not use the storage emulator.  Just a simple C# Web API application.

Comment: Why would you want to run a Web API from Command Line?

Comment: are you planning to self host the Web API application? are you targeting .Net Core 5.0 ?

Comment: What do you mean by "reduce my memory requirements", why would executing it from the command line change that at all?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Visual Studio Command Prompt to run VS in Commad prompt.

in Windows 8.1

On the Start screen, press CTRL + TAB to open the Apps list and then press V. The list will include all installed Visual Studio command prompts. (To open the Start screen, press the Windows logo key Windows logo on your keyboard.)

Choose the Developer Command Prompt (or the command prompt you want to use).

Comment: He mention a C# Web API application therefore your answer is incorrect.

Comment: @TechGuy - Can you give a bit more details in your answer when you update. Sorry but my knowledge of how to do this is pretty limited. Thank you